# How to put the bivariate/multivariate delta method into linear algebra notation?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics, delta-method

So I understand that the delta method allows us to approximate the expectation and variance of a random variable. Mathematically,

Let $Z = g(X,Y)$ where $X$ and $Y$ are random variables with $E[X] = \mu_X$ and $E[Y] = \mu_Y$ and $Var(X) = \sigma_X$ and $Var(Y) = \sigma_Y$. We do not know anything else about the distribution of $X$ and $Y$.

So approximating the $E[Z]$ and $Var(Z)$

Through Taylor's approximation:
$$g(X,Y) = g(\mu_x, \mu_y) + (X-\mu_X)\frac{d}{dX}g(\mu_x, \mu_y) + (Y-\mu_Y)\frac{d}{dY}g(\mu_x, \mu_y) + \frac{1}{2}(X-\mu_X)^2\frac{d^2}{dX^2}g(\mu_x, \mu_y) + (X-\mu_X)(Y-\mu_Y)\frac{d^2}{dXdY}g(\mu_x, \mu_y) + \frac{1}{2}(Y-\mu_Y)^2\frac{d^2}{dY^2}g(\mu_x, \mu_y) + \text{higher order terms}$$
We'll drop the higher order terms because we don't know anything about the higher moments of $X$ or $Y$.

So,
$$E[Z] = g(\mu_x, \mu_y) + E[(X-\mu_X)]\frac{d}{dX}g(\mu_x, \mu_y) + E[Y-\mu_Y)]\frac{d}{dY}g(\mu_x, \mu_y) + \frac{1}{2}E[(X-\mu_X)^2]\frac{d^2}{dX^2}g(\mu_x, \mu_y) + E[(X-\mu_X)(Y-\mu_Y)]\frac{d^2}{dXdY}g(\mu_x, \mu_y) + \frac{1}{2}E[(Y-\mu_Y)^2]\frac{d^2}{dY^2}g(\mu_x, \mu_y)$$

Notice that $E[Y - \mu_Y] = E[X - \mu_X]= 0$ by linearity. Therefore,

$$E[Z] = g(\mu_x, \mu_y) + \frac{1}{2}Var(X)\frac{d^2}{dX^2}g(\mu_x, \mu_y) + Cov(X,Y)\frac{d^2}{dXdY}g(\mu_x, \mu_y) + \frac{1}{2}Var(Y)\frac{d^2}{dY^2}g(\mu_x, \mu_y)$$

Okay, now I want to write this in linear algebra notation, but when I do this I lose the clear functions "Var()" and "Cov()." **I don't know if I'm just formulating this poorly and if I am please let me know**

$$E[Z] = g(\mu_X, \mu_Y) + E \left[ \begin{pmatrix}
 (X - \mu_X) & (Y - \mu_Y)\\ 
\end{pmatrix} \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{d^2}{dX^2} & \frac{d^2}{dXdY} \\
\frac{d^2}{dXdY} & \frac{d^2}{dY^2}
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
(X - \mu_X) \\
(Y - \mu_Y)
\end{pmatrix} \right] $$

I guess my question is can I actually do something here? Some matrix notation that I don't know. I would really love to use $COV()$ and $Var()$ like I did in the scalar formula. Did I just completely mess up the linear algebra formulation of the multivariate method?

I'd appreciate any help :-)

Comment: Please see the statement of multivariate delta method [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method#Multivariate_delta_method)

Comment: @Golden_Ratio Sorry, I don't think that helps. The example they did uses variance but I'm also unsure how they got from $Var(\nabla h(\beta)^T * B)$ to $\nabla h(\beta)^T Cov(B) \nabla h(\beta) $

Comment: For random column vector $X$, the variance matrix (or covariance matrix) is $Var(X)=E[XX']-E[X]E[X']. $  So for constant column vector $a$, we have $Var(a'X)=E[a'XX'a]-E[a'X]E[X'a]=a'E[XX']a-a'E[X]E[X']a=a'Var(X)a$

Comment: @Golden_Ratio Ah, I see. That makes a lot of sense. I'm really not trying to be annoying just really want to understand what's happening here. Above I have $$E[Z] = g(\mu_X, \mu_Y) + E \left[ \begin{pmatrix}
 (X - \mu_X) & (Y - \mu_Y)\\ 
\end{pmatrix} \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{d^2}{dX^2} & \frac{d^2}{dXdY} \\
\frac{d^2}{dXdY} & \frac{d^2}{dY^2}
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
(X - \mu_X) \\
(Y - \mu_Y)
\end{pmatrix} \right]$$ 

The random variable vectors are to the left and right of the constant matrix(the Hessian I think). Therefore, I can't take the expectations apart

Comment: @Golden_Ratio That is I can't do anything to get the hessian matrix out. Is that correct? As a result, I can't make use of Var() and Cov() like I can in the scalar form equation above?

Comment: See my answer. Also I think your question relates more to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_expansions_for_the_moments_of_functions_of_random_variables) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Taylor_series_in_several_variables) rather than the delta method

Answer (score 1):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{\operatorname{tr}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{\operatorname{Var}}$

Ignoring several issues I have with the exposition of your question (e.g. the equations should be approximations, the Hessian is not written correctly, and the derivatives are expressed with respect to random variables instead of the arguments of the function), I think the substance of your question is how to write the second order moment expressions in terms of variance or covariance matrices.

You could use traces. So let $Z=(X-\mu_x, Y-\mu_Y)'$ and let $H$ be half the hessian matrix.  Then since we are working with scalars, and using the property  $\tr(AB)=\tr(BA)$, we have $$\small E[Z'HZ]=E[\tr(Z'HZ)]=E[\tr(HZZ')]=\tr(E[HZZ'])=\tr(HE[ZZ'])=\tr(H\Var((X,Y)')).$$

where $\Var((X,Y)')$ denotes the [variance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix) of column random vector $(X,Y)'$.